# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape' even though the tensor is not None

Tags: pytorch, torch

I'm working with a resnet-based model to generate some feature embeddings

`feature = self.m_resnet(input)`

when I print

```
print('feature:', feature)
```

I get output like,

```
tensor([[[-5.2228e-01, -2.6507e-01, -1.4583e+00,  ..., -1.1618e+00,
          -3.9355e-01, -6.7108e-01],
         [-5.0633e-01,  9.0730e-01, -7.6286e-01,  ..., -6.7644e-01,
          -6.4372e-01,  4.2130e-02],
         [ 1.3522e+00,  1.1739e+00,  1.1027e+00,  ...,  1.0143e+00,
           1.0382e+00,  5.5187e-01],
         ...,
         [ 4.6489e-01, -1.2791e-01,  1.1394e+00,  ..., -2.3228e-01,
          -4.3149e-01,  3.1564e-01],
         [ 1.0425e+00,  9.7971e-01, -3.5113e-01,  ...,  4.3813e-01,
           3.7757e-01,  3.0367e-01],
         [-9.2531e-01, -3.5561e-01, -1.9557e-01,  ...,  1.2157e-01,
          -4.4008e-01, -9.3977e-02]],

        [[-5.7037e-01, -2.3364e-01, -1.3321e+00,  ..., -1.2070e+00,
          -4.7131e-01, -5.4751e-01],
         [-2.8480e-01,  8.5945e-01, -5.6804e-01,  ..., -8.7505e-01,
          -5.9196e-01, -4.7775e-02],
         [ 1.4179e+00,  1.3121e+00,  1.1915e+00,  ...,  9.6185e-01,
           9.4094e-01,  6.2634e-01],
         ...,
         [ 4.7378e-01, -2.0151e-01,  1.0540e+00,  ..., -2.1641e-01,
          -4.2161e-01,  2.7364e-01],
         [ 1.0599e+00,  8.7958e-01, -1.3885e-01,  ...,  3.7642e-01,
           3.1348e-01,  2.2855e-01],
         [-8.3528e-01, -3.6043e-01, -4.1944e-02,  ...,  7.9550e-02,
          -3.3973e-01, -9.5777e-02]],

        [[-4.6509e-01, -3.1390e-01, -1.3608e+00,  ..., -1.1940e+00,
          -4.0954e-01, -6.8436e-01],
         [-3.8707e-01,  9.0035e-01, -8.3244e-01,  ..., -7.7861e-01,
          -6.3493e-01,  1.8479e-02],
         [ 1.3674e+00,  1.2385e+00,  1.1890e+00,  ...,  9.8861e-01,
           1.1610e+00,  6.2035e-01],
         ...,
         [ 5.5125e-01, -1.4365e-01,  1.2544e+00,  ..., -1.9578e-01,
          -5.9983e-01,  3.9633e-01],
         [ 1.0217e+00,  1.0091e+00, -3.5424e-01,  ...,  3.7400e-01,
           4.3592e-01,  2.3972e-01],
         [-8.4321e-01, -3.9549e-01, -1.7280e-01,  ...,  1.3756e-01,
          -5.2992e-01,  1.3601e-03]],

        [[-4.4482e-01, -3.2837e-01, -1.4795e+00,  ..., -1.2002e+00,
          -4.2828e-01, -7.6532e-01],
         [-4.5860e-01,  9.2647e-01, -8.4050e-01,  ..., -7.8178e-01,
          -6.4275e-01,  6.4469e-02],
         [ 1.3156e+00,  1.2003e+00,  1.2451e+00,  ...,  1.1086e+00,
           1.2272e+00,  7.0043e-01],
         ...,
         [ 5.1705e-01, -1.1838e-01,  1.1950e+00,  ..., -2.6755e-01,
          -6.0813e-01,  4.4875e-01],
         [ 1.0428e+00,  1.0369e+00, -4.6282e-01,  ...,  4.1102e-01,
           4.8060e-01,  2.7509e-01],
         [-8.9088e-01, -3.8145e-01, -3.3285e-01,  ..., -1.1576e-03,
          -5.0087e-01,  3.1878e-02]]], device='cuda:0',
```

but when I print the shape,

```
print('shape:', feature.shape)
```

I get error,`AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'` on this print line.
According to above lines, feature is not None, then why I'm getting this error?

Comment: First you define `features` (with an `s`) but then you try to access `feature.shape` (without `s`), is that maybe the issue that you're accessing the wrong variable?

Comment: there's an error somewhere else in the code, what's the full stack trace? you are trying to access `shape` but the error message is about `size` leading me to believe when you access `shape` some other code accesses size of something else, leading to this error

Comment: I added this example just to explain the problem. Sorry for the mistakes in the question. I edited the question again

Comment: @flawr I can't share the original code because of confidentiality, but I'm using the same variable name to print the value as well as shape (I just add .shape in the latter runtime after the variable name)

Comment: @Matthias I have tried it with both .shape and .size() and both show the similar error

Comment: if your question is right now, there's no other explanation than some code which runs between the first print command and the second and sets feature=None. The error message says feature is None.

Comment: instead of just `print(feature.shape)` try doing in the exact same spot `print(feature)` see what comes out of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any other explanation than there is some code which runs between your first print command and your second and sets `feature=None`. Case in point:

```
>>> feature = "hello"
>>> print(feature)
hello
>>> feature = None
>>> print(feature.shape)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

If feature was still a tensor (or str or whatever), the error message should reflect that, like so:

```
>>> feature = "hello"
>>> print(feature)
hello
>>> print(feature.shape)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'shape'
```

If somehow feature was not in the scope and hadn't been defined at all, this should be the error message:

```
>>> print(feature_undefined.shape)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'feature_undefined' is not defined
```